# Memory-efficient alternative for distinct() in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

CosmosDB with MongoDB protocol layer limits the amount of memory that one query may consume. A distinct() query on the collection currently yields the following error message:

> Query exceeded the maximum allowed memory usage of 40 MB.

I would like to find a workaround that uses less memory but still can be implemented in *pure* MongoQL (as all the MongoQL code is currently abstracted in a generic way and should not be touched until an upstream fixis available.)

A possible solution would have been

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [ { $sample: { size: 5000 } } ]
).distinct("field_of_interest")
```

However the user might *just* be interested in a distinct value that was not drawn at random from the data.

Any ideas of how to limit the memory consumption? Thanks!

Issue exists with CosmosDB with MongoDB protocol layer 3.2 and 3.6.
Relevant issue on [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/16997).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved in protocol layer 3.6. Collection needs to be recreated with end point .mongo.cosmos.azure.com  or the protocol layer 3.2 to be upgraded to 3.6.

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Navtej S